# VPN in ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn

I installed VPN in Ubuntu server 14.04 which has the IP 192.168.20.5

I installed using link: http://grantcurell.com/2014/07/22/setting-up-a-vpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04/.

But the small difference I did is the client side is Windows 10 machine. So I used Securepoint SSL VPN.

I am able to Get the message as Connection established. IP: 10.8.0.6

But I am not able to ping 192.168.20.5 from my windows machine. Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I have to say that this answer is based on experience with the official OpenVPN Client and not Securepoint's one.

An OpenVPN server in a [routed setup](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting) creates a virtual TUN interface inside your server: this means that you have two interfaces (the physical `192.168.20.5` one and the virtual `10.0.8.1` one) that are independent and pretty much unknown to each other.

To let these two interfaces know each other and start talking, you need to enable the kernel's ip_forward feature. You can enable IP packet forwarding using the command `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` as root on a Debian-based distro; this change is not permanent (that is, it will be lost at poweroff).
[Read more about Linux IP routing/forwarding at this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/what-is-kernel-ip-forwarding)

After enabling IP forwarding you should be able to automagically ping the server from the client (as long as iptables' filter-FORWARD policy is ACCEPT).

Usually this is enough to get the tunnel working, but it depends on your actual configuration: for example, you may need to push routes to clients to let them know that they can reach a network through your tunnel. ([More info here](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) in paragraph "Expanding the scope of the VPN to include additional machines on either the client or server subnet.")

Be aware that you may not be able to ping your Windows client from the server (while you can ping your server from the Windows client) even thought you can ping a *nix client from the server successfully (tested with Linux and Android machines).

**Also remember that even if your machine appears as two different IP addresses, it is still the same machine, so if a service is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0), you can access that service through both addresses.**